# Lifting slowly makes you weaker

Tags: strength

I heard that lifting with a slow tempo not only makes it slower to build strength but also causes strength loss over time.

And that lifting at higher velocities is always better for strength growth.

Is this true?

Comment: It's already been answered but to put it simply, lifting slow is best for hypertrophy as it is more a "time under tension" method that causes metabolic damage. You still need a steady tempo for all your exercises but slow tempo is great for building muscle. More muscle doesn't equal more strength however. Just like German volume training, you will gain more muscle but be weaker strength wise after it's all over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dependent upon how we define strength. The common view of strength is that it is simply the ability to apply force: the higher the force, the greater the strength. And that is a reasonable definition in some contexts.

However, peak force production is not necessarily *functional* force production. To illustrate this, consider the process of lifting a barbell—any lift will do. In order to get the barbell moving, we need only apply a force that is greater than its [weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight). That could literally be one one-hundredth of a [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(unit)) greater than the weight of our load; if the force is greater, the load will move. However, imagine now that our load is 100 kilograms: [force = mass × acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), so we would accelerate the bar at a rate of one tenth of a millimetre per second per second. Needless to say, we would be exhausted before we would even discern the bar's movement.

Thus, in order for our strength to be *functional*, we must not only be able to meet the force requirements of moving our load, but we must move the load quickly enough so as not to fatigue before the end of the lift. And this can be done by either developing greater force, or greater endurance in producing that force. (Most commonly, we do both.) The latter is known as strength-endurance, but all strength necessarily depends on it.

Strength is therefore a subjective term that is only meaningful if we consider its application. Yes, in the purest sense, high lifting velocities require greater force production for any given load—remember that force = mass × acceleration—and they therefore stimulate the development of stronger (more forceful) muscle. However, slow tempo develops strength-endurance, and whilst force production is consequently lower, it is able to be applied for a greater time. This is, in many situations, equally important, and more in tune with our natural notions of what strength really is, since the application of strength is nearly always over some significant period of time.

I hope that gives you some perspective on the question.